# Looking for a cuvature tensor that adds up linearly

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

I'm looking for a **curvature tensor** "$C$" that characterizes the curvature like the Riemann tensor but **adds up linearly** regarding the metric tensor:

$C_{\mu\nu} (g_1+g_2) = C_{\mu\nu} (g_1)+C_{\mu\nu} (g_2)$

$C^{l}_{ijk}(a\cdot g)= a\cdot C^{l}_{ijk}(g)$

Is such a tensor possible to construct? How? (if not, why not?)

The Riemann tensor itself does not fulfill these requests
as for each (positive) constant $a$, $R^{l}_{ijk}(ag)= R^{l}_{ijk}(g)$ and
$R_{\mu\nu} (g_1+g_2) \neq R_{\mu\nu} (g_1)+R_{\mu\nu} (g_2)$
(For details see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452021/non-linearity-of-einsteins-field-equations))

Comment: How should this tensor “characterize the curvature”?

Comment: The only tensors that can be defined using the Riemannian metric and its partial derivatives of any order and are coordinate independent are the Riemann curvature, its covariant derivatives to any order, and tensors you can obtain by contracting these tensors with the metric tensor or each other.